# Populate datagridview with dates that in which the count depends on user input

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new in programming and only knows the basics. I just wanted to know how can I achieve this. Thankyou I have a datepicker, datagridview, textbox1 and tb_amount. I wanted to populate the datagridview with dates that depends on the datepicker and count that depends on the textbox1 and the tb_amount will be divided depends on the count. Like so: For example

```
date picker = 2-1-2019
textbox1    = 3
tb_amount   = 15
```

Output should in dgv should be like this:

```
Amount |  Date
-------------------
5      |  3-1-2019
5      |  4-1-2019
5      |  5-1-2019
```

Comment: Create a `DataTable`. Add two columns of type of `DateTime` and `Double`. Use a for loop to add rows to the `DataTable`. To add days to a `DateTime` you can use `yourDateTimeValue.AddDays`. At last set the table as `DataSource` of your `DataGrdiView`. Try something, then if you need help, ask a question sharing a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

The idea to acheave what you want to do is as follows:

You need to generate collection where each element represents a row and assign this collection as datasource to the datagridview. Which kind of collection and what element-class to choose depends on what interaction with the grid you allow to the user (add/remove rows, edit rows, etc.). See the Remarques of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Each column in your datagridview shows the value of a property of the Elements in the datasource. To define which property the column Displays, use the column's `DataPropertyName` property (see [DataPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname?view=netframework-4.7.2)). If you don't define any column in you datagridview, a column for each public property will be created (The caption of the column is the property Name).

Now in your specific case, you probably have a class to process your data. And I expect you have one property containing the date and one the amount, so something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public int Amount {get; set;}
    // and some other properties
}
```

Your datagridview should have two columns:

- column 1: HeaderText="My Amount Caption" and DataPropertyName="Amout"
- column 2: HeaderText="My Date Caption" and DataPropertyName="Date"

Now you can generate your collection as follows:

```
var myCollection = new List<MyClass>();
int numberOfRows = int.Parse(TextBox.Text);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++){
    var element = new MyClass() {
                      Date = datepicker.Value.AddDays(i),
                      Amount = tb_amount / numberOfRows
                  }
    myCollection.Add(element);
}
datagridview.datasource = myCollection;
```